# Find all link in a div element and disable them all

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, find, disable-link

Assume that I have some HTML elements like these :

```
<div id="content_div">
    <span><a href="some_link">Click me</a></span>
    <div> Hello everybody. Click <a href="some_link_else">me</a> to do something else</div>

    <a href="3rd_link"> Oops </a>
</div>
```

All that I need is get all "a" tags in the #content_div and disable all of them (I don't want user to click on them). How could I do that in Jquery?

Comment: What does you mean with "disable" links?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $("#content_div a").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Answer (score 17):

I would rely less on jQuery as it might be disabled by the user, so if you want a CSS solution, you can do it like

```
#content_div {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QHn6r/)

Edit: To be precise, use this declaration `#content_div a`

Comment: Doesn't work in IE before 11, but it's a great solution if that's acceptable!

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#content_div a").css({"color":"#888888", cursor: "default"}).click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/P4Fqq/

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't accept 2 answer at once, so I upvote your answer instead.

Comment: @quangtruong1985 See the updated code which changes the cursor to indicate it cannot be clicked.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways here:

1) `$('#content a').css({"pointer-events":"none"});`

2) `$('#content a').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: How can you enable the events after this?